# Dynamically adding and removing table rows - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to dynamically add and remove rows from a TableLayout.

The layout is defined in an xml file.

I am able to successfully remove a row, but when I call the corresponding addView command nothing happens.

```
table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);

table.removeView(row);

table.addView(row);
```

This results in a row being removed, but not being added again.

**Edit: It turns out it was adding if after all, just at the bottom of the screen instead of in the same location as it was removed from.**

I am able to add it in the correct position by specifying the index:

```
table.addView(row,4); // 4 happens to the the row
```

but I can not figure out how to determine the index of the row  , there does not seem to be a method to accomplish this. anyone know how do to that? (ie. if I did not know the index was 4 how could I figure that out)

Edit: included XML. this is just the row in question, there are other rows above and below it

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/row">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/field1"
            android:text="testing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dip"
        />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/field2"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:gravity="right"
        />



    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Your code works fine with a test layout.
Like to see your XML layout to comment further.

Comment: Did you have rows above and below the row in question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `hierarchyviewer` (in your SDK `tools/` directory) to determine if the row is truly not being added, or is being added but some layout parameters are messed up and so it is not appearing on-screen.

Comment: Didn't quite help here, but thanks for the heads up I hadn't taken a look at hierarchyviewer before.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int indexOfChild (View child) 

public View getChildAt (int index)
```

Both methods provided by TableLayout. ;-)