# How do I delete a TableRow from a button within it?

Tags: c#, android, button, tablerow

I'm new to all this, and I need a little help in this.

Here is my axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
    <Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/textView12" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Second Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Colleagues"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And here is my activity:

```
 public class Activity1 : Activity
{



    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        TableLayout t1 =(TableLayout) FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1); 
        Button add = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1); //this is just a test for the add button

        add.Click += delegate
        {
            TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);


            TextView tV_txt1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView tV_txt2 = new TextView(this);


            tV_txt1.Text = "A new row";
            tR.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            tV_txt2.Text = "Another new row ";

            tR.AddView(tV_txt1);
            tR.AddView(tV_txt2);

            t1.AddView(tR);

        };





    }


}
}
```

The problem is, that I can't find a way to delete from the button the row, the delete button is, of course without affecting the other rows. I would gladly appreciate some help.

Comment: Hello to everyone , altough it didnt appear when i posted the question, so im saying it from a comment.

Comment: Your title is a little confusing, did you mean to remove the `Button` from the `TableView`?

Comment: Hi Brian, sorry if i confused you, i have a tableLayout ,and on that layout i have a table row that has 4 columns, 3 textviews,one imageview and one button,called delete,when the user initiates a click event on the delete button, the current row must be deleted, along with the 3 textviews,imageview and button,without affecting other tablerows.Thats what i want. Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding and removing table rows - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407100/dynamically-adding-and-removing-table-rows-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find your answer here: [Dynamically adding and removing table rows - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407100/dynamically-adding-and-removing-table-rows-android)

Use the methods provided by table layout to get index of your row you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for exactly. You can consider setting the visibility of the `Button` to gone, like this.

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This will effectively removes the button but allows you bring it back by setting the visibility to `View.VISIBLE` in the future if you wish.

Comment: Keshi,pointed me to what i needed, i neded to delete the entire row,and also know how to do it so that i can keep the same row order when adding new rows.thx for the help :)